# Delphi - NULL-Terminated Character

Tags: c++, delphi

I Have A Pole Display Product for POS Systems, I want to display some data on the screen.
I have a C-Code to do that and its work fine
C-Code:

```
// demo.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


#include "windows.h"

int __cdecl main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
char in;
HMODULE hm;
long (*ou)();
long (*cu)();
long (*wp)(char*,long);
long (*ps)();
time_t tm;
char ss[64];

SetLastError( 0);
hm = LoadLibrary( "usbpd.dll");
printf( " hm = %p, %lu \n",hm,GetLastError());
if ( hm==NULL ) return 1;

SetLastError( 0);
ou = (long(*)()) GetProcAddress( hm,"OpenUSBpd");
printf( " ou = %p, %lu \n",ou,GetLastError());

SetLastError( 0);
cu = (long(*)()) GetProcAddress( hm,"CloseUSBpd");
printf( " cu = %p, %lu \n",cu,GetLastError());

SetLastError( 0);
wp = (long(*)(char*,long)) GetProcAddress( hm,"WritePD");
printf( " wp = %p, %lu \n",wp,GetLastError());

SetLastError( 0);
ps = (long(*)()) GetProcAddress( hm,"PdState");
printf( " ps = %p, %lu \n",ps,GetLastError());

printf( " OpenUSB = %ld \n", ou());


wp("Price: 5.00         ", 20);
wp("Total: 33.00        ", 20);
//for (long i=0;i<3;++i)
//  {
//  printf( " ps(1) = %ld \n", ps());

//  time( &tm);
//  sprintf( ss,"\x1b\x40%s",ctime( &tm));
//  wp( ss, strlen( ss));

//  if ( argc>1 ) for (int j=30;j<255;++j) { ss[0] = j; ss[1] = 0; wp( ss,1);}

//  printf( " ps(2) = %ld \n", ps());
//  }
printf( " CloseUSB = %ld \n", cu());

cin.get();

FreeLibrary( hm);

return 0;
}
```

and I Have a Code written in Borland Delphi to do the same as C-Code,
but after show my data it show a garbage characters.

Delphi Code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
TDLLFunc = function(): Integer;
ptr = ^TChar;
TChar = array[1..20] of PChar;

TDLLWriteFunc = function(ps_Text: ptr; pi_Length: Integer): Integer;

TForm1 = class(TForm)
  Button1: TButton;
  Button2: TButton;
  Edit1: TEdit;
  Button3: TButton;
  procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
private
  { Private declarations }
public
  { Public declarations }
  h: THandle;
  OpenUSBpd : TDLLFunc;
  CloseUSBpd: TDLLFunc;
  WritePD   : TDLLWriteFunc;
  PdState   : TDLLFunc;
end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var xx: TChar;
  pxx: ptr;
  i: Integer;
begin
  h:= LoadLibrary('D:\GlassTech\Taboon\Devices\PD23_26U\USBPD.DLL');

  if(h <> 0)then
    begin
      @OpenUSBpd := GetProcAddress(h, 'OpenUSBpd');
      @CloseUSBpd:= GetProcAddress(h, 'CloseUSBpd');
      @WritePD   := GetProcAddress(h, 'WritePD');
      @PdState   := GetProcAddress(h, 'PdState');

      OpenUSBpd;
    end;

  xx[1] := 'A';
  xx[2] := 'B';
  xx[3] := 'C';
  xx[4] := 'D';
  xx[5] := 'E';
  xx[6] := 'F';
  xx[7] := 'G';
  xx[8] := 'H';
  xx[9] := 'I';
  xx[10]:= 'J';
  xx[11]:= 'K';
  xx[12]:= 'L';
  xx[13]:= 'M';
  xx[14]:= 'N';
  xx[15]:= 'O';
  xx[16]:= 'P';
  xx[17]:= 'Q';
  xx[18]:= 'R';
  xx[19]:= 'S';
  xx[20]:= 'T';

  pxx:= @xx;

  WritePD(pxx, 0);

  CloseUSBpd;
end;
end.
```

Please Help, Thanks

Comment: I can't decide which code is worse, the C or the Delphi. I think you need to get a much firmer grip of the first principles of programming before proceeding.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Upvoted because you posted sample code. Even though most of us think your code is bad, we're glad you posted it because we can't answer your questions without it!

Comment: Mr. David, Thanks for your Reply
First of all the C code is a demo written by the producer and it works fine
about delphi code I tried all the attempts and all failed, including that referred by Mr. Andreas Rejbrand and Mr.Rudy Velthuis

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is very bad to redefine standard types, and this is almost what you do here:

```
ptr = ^TChar;
TChar = array[1..20] of PChar;
```

Indeed, `TChar` is way too similar to `char`, the pointer type of which is `PChar`. This is like insisting on the meaning "no" of the word "yes", and vice versa! In addition, you probably mean

```
TChar = array[1..20] of Char;
```

and the pointer to the first character is then, if `c: TChar`, equal to `@c[1]`. Furthermore, you might need to add a `#0` character to the end of the array. Anyhow, simply skip this horrible approach! Instead, use ordinary Delphi strings! These are always zero-terminated, and, since a string is a pointer to the actual in-memory array of characters, you can simply cast a string to a `PChar` to get a pointer to a zero-terminated array of characters.

However, I suppose the library is expecting an Ansi (or ASCII) string, and so we'll use `AnsiString` (`AnsiChar`) instead of `string` (`char`).

Do

```
TDLLWriteFunc = function(ps_Text: PAnsiChar; pi_Length: Integer): Integer; stdcall;

...

var XX: AnsiString;

...

XX := 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST';    
WritePD(PAnsiChar(XX), 0);
```

and the nulll terminator character will automatically be send to `WritePD`, because every Delphi string *does* end with a null character. In addition, `PAnsiChar(XX)` is the pointer to the first character in the string. *Also notice that I have used the stdcall calling convention! You probably need this, or, perhaps, cdecl.*

Also, are you sure that the `pi_Length` parameter isn't supposed to be the length of the string? If so, do

```
WritePD(PAnsiChar(XX), length(XX));
```

[Also, are you sure you want to `WritePD` and `CloseUSBpf` if `h = 0`?]

Comment: array of PChar is the main problem.

Comment: I can almost certainly say that he should be writing the length of the string, unless the DLL he is calling has some "magic" that it does when pi_Length is zero. Even then, that magic will probably rely on  C string semantics (null termination).

Comment: @David: indeed, TChar is an array[1..20] of PChar, so pxx contains a pointer to a PChar, and printing that as PChar will "print" the bytes of the PChar in xx[1], and, if there is no 0 byte in there, one or more of the bytes in xx[2|, etc. Of course that is garbage.

Answer (score 1):

Your `pxx` is a pointer to an `array[1..20] of PChar`, so `pxx` points to the first `PChar` in `xx`. Now if you start treating `pxx` as `PChar`, in the `wp()` call, it will treat the entire array of pointers like a string, i.e. it will "print" the **bytes** of the pointers, until it encounters the first zero byte. Of course that is garbage.

Your code contains a lot of errors an inconsistencies.

The first thing you should do is to redefine TChar:

```
type
  TChar = array[0..19] of Char; // NOT of PChar!
```

Get rid of `pxx` and `ptr` altogether. They are superfluous.

Now you can fill your array with characters (you were probably filling your array with `PChar`'s to literal **strings** like `'A'`, `'B'`, etc., and certainly not with `Char`'s) and then do

```
wp(xx, 20);
```

That is still terrible code, but it should work. Like others said, better use an `AnsiString` and cast:

```
myAnsiString := 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST';
wp(PAnsiChar(myAnsiString), Length(myAnsiString));
```

Just get rid of `xx` and the `TChar` type too.

---

More on strings and PChars in an article I wrote: [PChars: no strings attached](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pchars.html). I think you should read it.

Comment: Sorry for this off-topic comment, but I just realized you're Rudy from Rudy's Delphi Corner. That's awesome, it's so cool that you're on this site, you make Delphi that much more awesome. Also +1 for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using stdcall like this, and using PAnsiChar:

```
 type
      TDLLFunc = function : Integer; stdcall;
      TDLLWritePAnsiCharLongIntFunc = function(ps_Text: PAnsiChar; pi_Length: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
```

Also, Andreas is right, the writing the string part could be simply:

```
procedure WriteLetters;
var 
 s:String;
begin
     s := 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST';
     WritePD( PAnsiChar(s), Length(s));
end;
```